# Turning radio buttons into a css switch

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this markup produced by a custom control panel:

```
<div class="block" id="manage-pop3">
    <h2 class="head icon-2"><span>Manage POP3/IMAP Service</span></h2>
    <p>Here you can enable or disable the POP3/IMAP service for your account. This is used for sending mail to email clients like Outlook, therefore if POP3/IMAP is disabled, our online Webmail client will also not function.</p>
    <p class="center">
        <label><input type="radio" name="pop3_enabled" id="pop3_enabled-1" value="1" checked="checked">Enabled</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="pop3_enabled" id="pop3_enabled-0" value="0">Disabled</label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="">
    </p>
</div>
```

I would like to turn it into a single css slide switch like these: http://www.cssflow.com/snippets/toggle-switches/demo

I would like the submit button to be pressed when the switch is toggled.

I have been looking, but just can't get my head round it.

Regards,
Matthew Stratford.

Comment: You can style it like this: http://www.cssflow.com/snippets/toggle-switches/demo/scss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they’re doing here is pretty simple but the way they’ve structured their code unfortunately makes it very difficult for anyone but the author to follow.

I’ve broken it down into just the basic concept which hopefully is easier to understand.

The general idea here is just to take advantage of the ‘adjacent sibling selector’ `+` in CSS to write different styles when a previous element is one that receives the `:checked` pseudo class.

```
input[type=radio] + label {
 /* label styles */
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label {
 /* label styles when next to selected radio button */
}
```

From there they are abusing the living daylights out of the adjacent sibling selector to add another element that slides under the label text to indicate which item is selected. Side note: Doing this is hacky as hell since it requires you set fixed widths and heights everywhere (generally bad practice since it makes responsive layouts extremely complex).

Code snippet below. Please ask questions if there’s anything else about this you’d like to know!

*Note: I’m using `<!-- remove whitespace -->` in the HTML to workaround [a common problem with display: inline-block](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/). This problem does not exist if you use flexbox, which I’d be happy to show you how to do [if you can support it](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox).*

```css
/* Broswer reset */
* { margin:0; padding:0 }


/* menu base styles */
menu[role=radiogroup] {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ddd;
  line-height: 40px; /* Set height */
  position: relative; /* Make this the parent of absolutely positioned elements */
}

/* hide radio buttons */
menu[role=radiogroup] input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

/* Label base styles */
menu[role=radiogroup] input[type=radio] + label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative; /* draw above selection indicator */
  z-index: 1; /* draw above selection indicator */
  transition: none; /* No delay by default */
}
/* Label selected styles */
menu[role=radiogroup] input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  transition: 0 400ms; /* Add a delay before applying these styles */
  color: white;
}

/* Selection indicator (blue box) default styles */
menu[role=radiogroup] .selection-indicator {
  background: dodgerblue;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 0;
  transition: 400ms; /* animate changes, in this case: position */
}


/* Manually set selection indicator position based on state
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* First item selected */
menu[role=radiogroup] input[type=radio]:checked + label + input[type=radio] + label + .selection-indicator {
  left: 0;
}

/* Second item selected */
menu[role=radiogroup] input[type=radio] + label + input[type=radio]:checked + label + .selection-indicator {
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<menu role="radiogroup">
    <input type="radio" name="pop3-toggle" id="pop3-enabled" checked>
    <label for="pop3-enabled">Enabled</label><!-- remove whitespace
 
 --><input type="radio" name="pop3-toggle" id="pop3-disabled"><!-- remove whitespace
 --><label for="pop3-disabled">Disabled</label>
    
    <span class="selection-indicator"></span>
</menu>
```

Comment: Thanks for that! It certainly headed me in the right direction! It now works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the CSS sliding switch issue, just having a look at the source of your demo helps a lot. I suppose you have use a browser suitable for web dev, so you can just right-click the widget in your demo and "Inspect element" or whatever the name of the command is.

It's actually easy, the `<input type='radio'>` elements are not even displayed. Look at the `<label>` elements instead.

Regarding the submit button-pressing, what you actually want is not to press the button when the switch is toggled but to call whatever action is associated to a press on that button. Or am I mistaken?

For a form, that action would typically be a call to its [`submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.submit) method, but maybe you want more? You'll have to use JavaScript in that case.

**edit:** By the way, the demo is in an `<iframe>`, which may hinder your ability to examine the DOM inside it using certain dev tools, so <s>take that into account</s> go [there](http://s3.cssflow.com/snippets/21-toggle-switches/index.html) instead.